# SwiftUI: How to Disable List Scrolling on Reusable View

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I've got an interesting glitch in SwiftUI -

I'm using a List as part of my interface that is intended to be un-scrollable. This is how I've designed it:

```
List {
    ForEach(myArr) {
        ...
    }
}
.listStyle(.plain)
.onAppear { 
    UIScrollView.appearance().isScrollEnabled = false
    UIScrollView.appearance().showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
}
```

Now, when I first load the view containing this list, it works perfectly; you cannot scroll this list. However, if I navigate to a different page in my application and then back to the page containing this list (which creates a new instance of the view), scrolling becomes enabled.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.disabled(true)` on the list to disable interaction with the list.